# How to write 'file3.csv' file contents to existing csv file to specific columns?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Following is my input csv file contents

**file3.csv:**

```
a,ab
b,cd
c,nav
d,test
name,port
```

I want to write this into a existing csv file, in a specific column numbers.

For example:

```
I want to write, a,b,c,d,name into a column number --- AA
And I need to write ab,cd,nav,test,port into a column number ---AB
```

Python Script:

```
import csv

f1 = open ("file3.csv","r") # open input file for reading

with open('file4.csv', 'wb') as f: # output csv file
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    with open('file3.csv','r') as csvfile: # input csv file
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:  
            row[7] = f1.readline() # edit the 8th column 
            writer.writerow(row)
f1.close()
```

I am getting following error:

> MacBook-Pro:test$ python three.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "three.py", line 10, in 
>        row[7] = f1.readline() # edit the 8th column
>   IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Could you provide a few lines of `file4.csv`? It would be helpful to reproduce your error.

Comment: also add headers if they exist

Answer (score 0):

You can not use an index into a list for an element that does not already exist.  You will need to increase the length of the row before assigning elements to specific indices.

If you want to assign to `row[7]` try this before:

```
if len(row) < 8:
    row += [None] * (8 - len(row))
```

So, your inner loop will likely need to look something like:

```
for row in reader:
    if len(row) < 8:
        row += [None] * (8 - len(row))
    new_values = f1.readline().strip().split(',')
    row[7:7+1+len(new_values)] = new_values
    writer.writerow(row)
```